# Varnish vcl_backend_response detect vcl_recv return (hash)

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

On a multiple website set-up using varnish 5.1 on port 80, I don't want to cache all domains.
That is easily done in vcl_recv.

```
if ( req.http.Host == "cache.this.domain.com" ) {
    return(hash);
}

return(pass);
```

Now in vcl_backend_response I want to do some processing for cached domains.

Of course I can do if( bereq.http.Host == "cache.this.domain.com" ), but is there a way to know if it was a return(hash) or a return(pass) call in vcl_recv from within vcl_backend_response?

I thought that this could make sense but couldn't find the information.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really makes me wonder why you need such processing in the first place.

I don't think there's a way to tell directly how you landed into `vcl_backend_response`. So I suppose you can set a flag and check on that later, i.e.:

```cpp
sub vcl_recv {
    if ( req.http.Host == "cache.this.domain.com" ) {
        set req.http.return_type = "hash";
        return(hash);
    }
    set req.http.return_type = "pass";
    return(pass);
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    if( bereq.http.return_type == "pass" ) ...
}
```

Comment: I'll accept your answer.  i was hoping there would be a more elegant way.  i wanted to cache in vcl_backend_response backend errors, and only for those that entered via hash to restart the query hooking it to a permanent fail_be to try and fish it from cache. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the ad-hoc approach suggested by @Daniel V., an alternative that might fit your needs is:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (!bereq.uncacheable) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This let's you execute the extra processing only for cacheable objects.

Comment: Not sure about his as uncacheable is to do with hit for pass

Comment: `bereq.uncacheable` will be set to `true` (this is a read-only variable) on passes in the client side or when hitting on a HFP object. As I said, this might fir or not in your use case depending on yours specific needs.

Comment: I'll try this and let you know.  Thanks.  I just hope this doesn't get set to true if a previous request returned a 503 (misbehaving backend time to time spitting a few empty response for a couple seconds and restart comes to early for backend to change it's mind )

Comment: OK!!  Tried it and it's just what i needed!!  Really sorry I had overlooked your response. I had tried using beresp.uncacheable and didn't match what I wanted.  I hadn't worked out those two properties had different meaning.  It's your response I should have accepted :-/